# A Windows-compatible C IDE that will be able to compile FFmpeg?

Tags: c, windows, compiler-construction, ide, ffmpeg

I want to set up an environment on my PC (Win7x64) that I will be able to combine these projects and compile them into one executable:

- [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org)
- [AMV codec tools](http://code.google.com/p/amv-codec-tools/)

For this I need an environment that can compile/debug both the above projects (creating a Windows compatible exe).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page  NetBeans can handle MinGW.  (Might be other IDEs, but I've used MinGW under NetBeans so I know it can.)

Comment: Any further guidance on my particular issue for combining these two libraries into one will be also highly appreciated.

Comment: Haven't even compiled either myself.  Just saw that the MinGW is compatible, and I'm assuming it is for AMV codec tools since it uses FFmpeg's plugin structure.  As for getting NetBeans to play along....  Well...  Are you sure you really need to compile it in an IDE?  What exactly are you wanting to do?  If so, you should just be able to modify the makefile to be compatible with what NetBeans expects (or maybe modify the NetBeans makefile to call the FFmpeg makefile).

Comment: Also, MinGW's MSYS might be of value since it should contain all of the GNU-esque tools you'll need.

Comment: Basically, [here](http://code.google.com/p/amv-codec-tools/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Fffmpeg) is where the FFmpeg resides inside the amv-codec-tools project. I want to compile the amv-codec-tools with the updated FFmpeg. I don't know how to do it. Once I know I can make an automated too that compiles it with the current ver. of FFmpeg automatically or on demand.

Answer (score 1):

[eclipse](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20setup%20Eclipse%20IDE%20for%20FFmpeg%20development) is recommended with official wiki